# Would this be considered keyword stuffing?

Tags: seo, html, url

we have a website with a lot of galleries filled under a couple of different categories. A while ago we migrated all the URLs from for example:

```
http://domain.com/blog/post/1225/bakemonogatari-cosplay-hanekawa-black-by-aki/
```

to something like this

```
http://domain.com/cosplay/bakemonogatari-cosplay-hanekawa-black-by-aki-1225/
```

Funny thing was that 2 days after this, we were hit by almost a total drop of traffic from what seems to be Google panda. In the past 6 months I fixed every imaginable thing I could think of. This made me think that google might consider this as keyword stuffing and therefore dropped the site from the results because of the URLs?

I am now thinking of changing the URL schema to simply:

```
http://domain.com/bakemonogatari-cosplay-hanekawa-black-by-aki-1225/
```

Do you think that's better? Or is there a better solution such as /blog/ subfolder or somehting?

Thanks

Comment: Google's normal algorithms pickup keyword stuffing, Panda can detect low quality or thin articles with a lot of keywords on page (as well as many other things, Google Panda is about user experience basically). Without reviewing your pages its hard to tell... Are your articles over 450 words ish? can you share the website in question.

Comment: Ah, just found your site within a comment below. It's a tricky one because your site is mostly composed of images, I can't find a  confirm that using low text ratio and high ratio of images is good for Google panda or not.. it just mentions thin pages with not a lot of text so this could be one of many problems... Additionally are the images on this site unique? if not then its possible you been slapped for excessive duplicate content, duplicate content is not only text based and indeed image based, http://www.searchenginenews.com/blog/entry/beware-google-updates-image-search

Comment: Thanks. This made me think. I've seen pages with a lot less text rank much better, but they don't have such big galleries. Concerning the duplicate content, I would have to say that a lot of those images are searchable trough Google image search, but there are also quite a few that aren't. All the included images have custom generated thumbnails, which are unique, but I'm not sure if that matters. Do you think that by displaying perhaps 10 images per page and a "show more" button would help with this? This and the URL change seems to be the only thing I can think of to fix.

Comment: There are some pages with over 100 images per gallery.

Comment: Well Google's Panda update is about user experience so if your pictures are duplicate and found else where then something has to give that why you are better, the pages are pretty thin and you could try to increase main gallery page to 400+ words. show more buttons will only make the pages thinner so best to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, I'm very glad. First of all, this is NSFW. So sorry about that, if it bothers you, please ignore the rest of the comment. Anyway, if you search for "Saimin Yuugi Hentai" (without the quotes) on Google, you can notice that most of the results are completely off, while Simply Otaku is pushed to the second page even though it's the only one with any normal written text from these.

This really makes my head hurt. I can't possibly figure out what is wrong. Then again an article I wrote with over 450 words ranks very well even though there's a lot more quality competition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you were hit by loss of traffic is about keyword stuffing. Your URL are clean.

When you change URL, Google takes a little time to take into account new ones. In general, you lose traffic and then, it comes back.

Make sure your 301 redirects from old URLs to new ones work well and wait.

Comment: The traffic dropped after a day, but the next day it dropped (because of the new URLs) but it jumped back up the next day, and then in about two days it disappeared from Google when panda was updated.

It's been at least 6 months since then and nothing improved, even thought the website was fine during all the previous panda updates, so this was the only thing I changed.

Comment: Did you put 301 redirects and clean your website? (you can share your website URL)

Comment: All the posts were redirected with 301, this is the URL:
http://simplyotaku.com